# Same DLL loaded twice in a process

Tags: winapi, com, activex

I have an ActiveX control (foo.dll), when I embedded the same in the IE and start the page. I could see that the process explorer shows two instances of the foo.dll loaded from the same location.

This causes the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH to be called twice and the global data structures gets initialized twice.

Is there a way to workaround this ? how does the windows loader works ?

Thanks,
  Velu

Comment: Any chance is this a mixed-mode application?  If so, then if you also have multiple AppDomains, then it is possible to load the same DLL, but in each AppDomain.

Comment: I've seen this before where once was mapped as "Image" and the other as "Data" at different base addresses and sizes

Answer (score 1):

`DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` should only be called once per instance of the DLL . . . are the DLL's loaded at the same base address, i.e., is the HINSTANCE in DllMain the same?  Are they loaded from the exact same path? Different paths result in diffent loaded modules. Is it being unloaded in between the two loads?  Are you sure you're seeing `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` and not `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`?

Comment: Hi Micheal, Surprisingly both the instances gets loaded from the same path and the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH is what I was referring to ..

Comment: Is the DLL being unloaded in between?  Can you post the code to your DllMain?

Answer (score 1):

[LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179(VS.85).aspx) contains an extra flag for how to treat the dll. I suspect this is why you see it appear more than once.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to protect your global data with a singleton-ish initialize function.

How many global structures do you have anyway?

Answer (score 0):

DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH is called whenever a process loads the DLL.

Use a counter to determine how many processes are attached, and only do initialization when the first one attaches.

You also need to set things up to [share memory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/Share_memory_throuth_DLL.aspx) between instances of the DLL, and store the counter in that, as well as your global memory that you only want to initialize once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the observation can be explained by the fact that the dll you refer is instantiating a COM (ActiveX) object that is defined as STA (single threaded apartment). Any .Net dll that refer to an STA com object will have a new image loaded in memory for each thread that use those COM objects.
At least that is the behavior that looks to happen to us.